# WXwidgets for GUI in C++:

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets, codeblocks

I am totally beginner in creating GUIS and I am using wxwidgets to create GUI programs in CodeBlocks. I am following this tutorials here:

http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=WxSmith_tutorials

I have figured out how to create dialog boxes and frames. Now, I have created in C++ a program that reads information from a .txt file and calls a method displayInfo() that prints this information using cout. What I would like to do is to print this information on a single window, by clicking a button, say: "Print Information".

The part that I am finding hard, is how to call my displayInfo() method from the main.cpp of the frame, and how to display that information on a window, instead of the terminal. I tried to import the header file of my class in the main.cpp of the frame, and called displayInfo(), but I do not think this is the right way to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wxWidgets has some predefined dialog boxes for display small quantities of text.

See [wxMessageBox description](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_dialogfunctions.html#wxmessagebox)

Otherwise you will have to use a DrawText method on the panel or window.

Comment: Yes, this works, but if there need to be displayed large quantities of text, it will not work. Would you have any suggestions for this case?

Answer (score 2):

I reccomend using a text control and then redirecting cout to the text control

Like this:

```
#include <iostream>

  wxTextCtrl *control = new wxTextCtrl(...);

  wxStreamToTextRedirector redirect(control);

  // all output to cout goes into the text control until the exit from current
  // scope
```

For more discussion of neat variations on this trick, take a look at:

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxtextctrl.html

Scroll down to the section titled:  wxTextCtrl and C++ streams